# How to replace all occurring same character like ' with ;$39

Tags: javascript

I am using following code, in which i want to replace all ' with ;$39 but its not working fine . It's replace only first ' .

`var searchUserName = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentMain_UserSearchColl").value.replace("/\'/g", ";$39;");`

For example: Ram's's .Output: Ram;$39s;$39s

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to put the regexp inside double quotes. Remove them.

```
value.replace(/'/g, ';$39;')
```

Also note that you need not "escape" the single quote. (Thanks @Paul S. for pointing)

Comment: That single `'` quote also doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @Thrustmaster what about `value.split("'").join(';$39;')` ?